# Mockito use in Java language?

Tags: java, mockito, developer-tools

How is Mockito used by Java Developers at entry level ?If yes where
Is it important for coding or just related to testing part ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mockito is used only for testing, and it is usually used with JUnit to provide mocks for dependencies. This means you are able to unit test a class / method, without having to rely on the actual implementation of other dependencies, classes, or services, especially if they are not yet available.

More details here: https://site.mockito.org/